# How to unpack a nested array in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my data is a mix of lists and dictionaries.

I need to create a data frame for my_stats.

I can can get to the data at (my_stats[0]['stats'],['data']), through

df = pd.DataFrame (my_stats[0]["stats"]["data"])

```
area             key  ... Scrum Errors  Confirm Try
```

0     C1        Kick Off  ...          NaN          NaN
1    NaN  Passive Tackle  ...          NaN          NaN
2     D1           Rucks  ...          NaN          NaN
3     D1        Lineouts  ...          NaN          NaN
4    NaN  Neutral Tackle  ...          NaN          NaN

but I need my data frame to show the game _id as the 1st column of the data frame.

here is some of the data of two of the matches.

Please assist.

my_stats = [{**'_id': 'GLEvHIL2020031419A'**, 'stats': {'data': [{'area': 'C1', 'key': 'Kick Off', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 0, 'endSecond': 6, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:06', 'Kick Off Fielded': 'Unsuccessful'}, {'key': 'Passive Tackle', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 9, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:09', 'value': 9, 'subMetric': 3, 'rtp': []}, {'area': 'D1', 'key': 'Rucks', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 9, 'endSecond': 19, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:19'}, d': 1175, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:19:35', 'value': 8, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}, {'area': 'C2', 'key': 'Rucks', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 1176, 'endSecond': 1178, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:19:38'}, {'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 1176, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:19:36', 'value': 6, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}, {'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 1177, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:19:37', 'value': 12, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}, {'key': 'Tackle Assist', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 1184, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:19:44', 'value': 7, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}]}}, {**'_id': 'HJSvMON2020031419A'**, 'stats': {'data': [{'area': 'C2', 'key': 'Kick Off', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 1, 'endSecond': 5, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:05', 'Kick Off Fielded': 'Successful'}, {'area': 'C2', 'key': 'Kick Off', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 2, 'endSecond': 5, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:05', 'Kick Off Fielded': 'Successful'}, {'key': 'Kick Fielded Successfully', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 4, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:04', 'value': 7, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}, {'key': 'Effective Ruck', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 6, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:06', 'value': 3, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}, {'key': 'Effective Ruck', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 6, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:06', 'value': 2, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}, {'area': 'C2', 'key': 'Rucks', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 6, 'endSecond': 10, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:10'}, {'area': 'C2', 'key': 'Rucks', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 6, 'endSecond': 9, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:09'}, {'key': 'Good Pass', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 10, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:10', 'value': 9, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': [{'key': 'Good Pass', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 16, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:16', 'value': 9, 'subMetric': None}]}, ]}}]

Comment: I think there is some missing `'` or `{}` in your variable `my_stats`. You can correct that. Also, add some sample output that you are expecting.

Comment: please add a clean sample. remove unnecessary information and give a compact one.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort.  Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Thank you guys, @TomasCourreges figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_stats)

def pd_unnest_dict(df, col):
    exploded_col = df[col].apply(pd.Series)
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns=col), exploded_col], axis=1)

df = pd_unnest_dict(df, 'stats')
df = df.explode('data')
df = pd_unnest_dict(df, 'data')
```

Comment: Tomas you legend. Thank you very much. I am 3 weeks into programming and giving it a good go. But it helps to stand on the shoulders of giants.